# Spring Dependancy Injection: FileNotFound Exception

Tags: java, spring, dependency-properties

[image]

I'm learning spring dependency injection. I have 2 types of code. One works and one doesn't... But, they both work for the person who made the tutorial.

The commented code gives me the error shown below.

```
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //ApplicationContext factory = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");

    //The code below works
    BeanFactory factory = new XmlBeanFactory(new FileSystemResource("Beans.xml"));
    HelloWorld obj = (HelloWorld) factory.getBean("helloworld");

    obj.getMessage();
}
```

Beans.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd           
       ">


    <bean id="helloworld" class="com.vulab.hellow.HelloWorld">
        <property name="message" value="Hello World" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Error message when I use *ApplicationContext*

Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [Beans.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [Beans.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Comment: file Beans.xml or file beans.xml ? check the case ?

Comment: Its the same in the IDE. @JeromeC.

Comment: Where did you place your Beans.xml file? Is it inside a source folder (does it get copied to your classes folder whenever you compile your app)?

Comment: @ClaudioFernandez How do I make sure of that? I opened my classes folder..didnt see anything called Beans.xml

Comment: put your Beans.xml into the same directory of the class which call it. If you use maven, you can put it in the resource folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `XmlBeanFactory` to work, `Beans.xml` would have to be in the same directory as the calling class.

An easy alternative is make sure that `Beans.xml` is located in your classpath. You could copy them into `src\resources` and then use:

```
ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");
HelloWorld obj = (HelloWorld) applicationContext.getBean("helloworld");
```

`ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` is more convenient as absolute file locations do not need to be specified.

Note: As of Spring 3.1 `XmlBeanFactory` is a [*deprecated*](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/XmlBeanFactory.html) which means that an alternative such as this should be used should you change from 3.0.

Comment: That WORKED !! Thank You... Just curious what's the point of having these two types of codes?

Comment: They are different readers, `XmlBeanFactory` doesnt read from the classpath by default.

Answer (score 1):

For the `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext`, the Application Context XML file will need to be available in your ClassPath.

If you are using standard Maven directory layout, you will want to place your `Beans.xml` file in `src/main/resources`.

If you are running from your IDE (it looks like you are using Eclipse from your screenshot, though you did not explicitly state your IDE), you will want to go into your Properties->Java Build Path and add `src/main/resources` to the build path.

Good luck, hope this helps!